Why doesn't Ubuntu 20.04 recognize my flash drive
Previously, Ubuntu did recognize my flash drive, but the mount point had root as the user. This was only a minor difficulty, as I just had to put in my password to unmount it. I also found that if the flash drive was not plugged into a USB port, Ubuntu would not start. So, I tried to change the mount point to a location where I was the owner. Now Ubuntu will not recognize the flash drive at all, and I can't seem to fix it, or at least get back to where I started.
I tried to use the instructions at https://draculaservers.com/tutorials/why-is-my-usb-not-mounting-in-ubuntu/
But when I got to the command below, I got the following error message.
bob@bob-Inspiron-5591-2n1:~$ sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /media/USB
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sda1': No such file or directory
ntfs-3g 2022.10.3 integrated FUSE 28 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on
Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2022 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009-2020 Erik Larsson
Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>
Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).
Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows
Plugin path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ntfs-3g
News, support and information:  https://github.com/tuxera/ntfs-3g/
I've used various flavors of Linux for a long time and love it. But I'm not particularly tech savvy, so you will have to treat me as a beginner. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What ever and only you can know was on that drive the OS wants to access it on startup. No way anyone here can know what you did.
